# Subversion svn+ssh access and prohibit copying files from server via SSH

Tags: linux, svn, ssh

System environment :

Server: Centos 6.2

Client: Windows + TortoiseSVN + putty

I have installed subversion in centos, created repository on server, and configured svn+ssh access way using key authentication. Everything works fine.
But I have a question about svn user using svn+ssh mode.

The svn user have a ssh key, so he can access subversion server and of course he can also access Centos server by SSH using the key authentication. Further, he can copy subversion repository files(Specifically /db files) from centos server using like WinSCP tool base on SSH.
So, I wanna know if there is a way that let the svn user just can access svn repository via svn+ssh and can't copy repository files from centos directly via ssh accessing?
If he can copy repository files from centos server via ssh, I think the svn access control realized by conf/authz file doesn't make any sense and svn repository isn't safe.

I just learn how to create a svn+ssh subversion server, so maybe my knowledge isn't enough, please give me a idea or just tell me whether a solution exists.
If can't prohibit copying files from Linux server via SSH, I will use svn or http(s) access mode.

Thank you!

Comment: Gino you are right,
follow this:
http://jimmyg.org/blog/2007/subversion-over-svnssh-on-debian.html

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this problem.

add command into authorized_keys file to disable ssh shell login and scp, but enable svn+ssh, like this:

"/usr/bin/svnserve -t -r /svn/test/",no-port-forwarding,no-pty,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding

after add your authorized_keys file will like this:

command="/usr/bin/svnserve -t -r /svn/test/",no-port-forwarding,no-pty,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding ssh-rsa A......................................................................

I think this is one solution, do your have others? Please let me know.